# Javascript responseXML memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, tree, xmlhttprequest

I've been tracking down some memory leaks in a Javascript file I've been working with, and I've found one of the last reamining culprits.  When I get the responseXML from an XMLHttpRequest, I don't think the response ever gets deleted.  I don't know how to delete it, I tried removing the child nodes and then setting it to null (Hoping garbage collection would work) and I also tried using the delete key word.  Neither of these things seemed to help.  Below is some of the offending code (I omitted some timeout stuff that removes the request itself, but that is not what's causing the memory leak).

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChange1;
request.send();
}

function onReadyStateChange1()
{
    if (4 == request.readyState)
    {
        if (request.status == 200)
        {
            request.responseXML;     //It leaks even if I just do this.
            //me.ParseData(request.responseXML);
            me.disconnected = 0;
        } else
        {
            me.disconnected += 1;
        }
        request.onreadystatechange = noop;    //noop is an empty function
        request = null;
        me = null;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, I don't even call ParseData, I just put `request.responseXML;` and it still leaks.  If I comment that line out as well, though, the leak is gone.  Meaning the leak is not in the ParseData function or elsewhere, it is the responseXML.  I believe it has to do with the tree structure of responseXML, the DOM tree is probably not being cleaned properly.  If anyone could help me that would be great.

Comment: why do you do a request.abort()?

Comment: I suppose there it is not absolutely necessary, I just copy and pasted it from the timeout code and it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: What browser? What if you're using `responseText` instead? By the way to have people see your comments on their comment use `@` to notify for example @Cas will notify Caspar.. without it chances are low they'll see your comment.

Comment: @Shadow-Wizard It's actually being used in a Windows 7 gadget, and I could use responseText but it'd become a huge issue with parsing. I use responseText elsewhere (where no XML file exists) and it doesn't seem to cause any problems. I think it's due to the tree structure of responseXML. Also, thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you're sure there's memory leak I fear you'll have to parse the XML yourself.. like mentioned before jQuery can greatly help you. BTW you misused the `@`, space must be omitted not replaced by `-`.. however first three letters are enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responseXML that IE returns is actually MSXML DOM instead of MSHTML DOM, so that developers can use selectNodes and selectSingleNode functions. MSXML DOM has its own [garbage collection mechanism](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304227), so that you'll not notice memory free right after the DOM is out of scope. Therefore, I would say that this is probably not a true memory leak but a delay free.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the response handler as an anonymous function sharing the same scope like:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (4 == request.readyState){
    ...
  }
}
```

Does it leak too?

Comment: Yes it does, as I've stated in the question I'm almost 100% sure the problem is with getting the responseXML.

Comment: That's weird. I've used the code above for years, without leaks. Did you try with another simpler XML?